# How does getmaxyx change the value of a passed variable?

Tags: c, ncurses

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {

  initscr();

  int height, width;
  getmaxyx(stdscr, height, width);

  endwin();

  printf("width  : %i\n", width);
  printf("height : %i\n", height);

  return 0;
}
```

result is
width  : 148
height : 38

How the width and height were changed without passing a pointer

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/getmaxyx

Comment: Because it is a macro, which is not a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getmaxyx is a macro

```
#define getmaxyx(win,y,x) (y = getmaxy(win), x = getmaxx(win))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you read https://linux.die.net/man/3/getmaxyx you'll see:

> Notes All of these interfaces are macros. A "&" is not necessary
> before the variables y and x.

Comment: the theory is that this is a Q&A site. The community will decide if it is a worthwhile answer that could serve others.

Comment: @ayoubkafi well, I upvoted the question and answers because this was the first time this was asked on Stack Overflow (search `getmaxyx macro`).